# How to show non-matching results with join (sqlserver)

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I'm trying this code

```
SELECT  e.codartp AS ARTICLE,e.codartc AS COMPONENTS, sa.CODALM as WAREHOUSE, 
sa.unidades as UNITS, sa.UBICACION as 'LOCATION' FROM escandallo e 
left join STOCKALM sa on e.codartc = sa.codart  
where trim(e.codartp) = '30393' and sa.CODALM = 0
```

and it shows like this

```
ARTICLE COMPONENTS  WAREHOUSE   UNITS   LOCATION
  30393     310        0         376    XHY40081
  30393     C042       0         302    NULL
  30393     C042       0         1158   WCY40082
```

but I would like it to show non-matching results aswell. I know there is another component for that article, but it is not showing because table stockalm doesn't include items with 0 stock.

Is it possible to show every component even if it is not found in the joined table?

Thank you very much

Comment: When you refer to a column in your where clause from the unpreserved table (STOCKALM) of your outer join, that logically turns your outer join into an inner join. So move the filter into your join condition as already suggested.

Comment: And best practice is to use 2 part names - include the schema name with the table name. I also suggest you use more descriptive aliases in general. Here it does not make much difference but in more complex queries that refer to very similarly named objects it does. Develop GOOD habits.

Comment: I tried moving the filter into the join condition, but it shows every article in the table, not only the one I filtered :(

Comment: Ok, it is fixed, thank you. I added the stockalm to the join condition and the product as it was (a where). Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Condition in **ON** Clause Instead of **Where**Clause

```
SELECT  e.codartp AS ARTICLE,e.codartc AS COMPONENTS, sa.CODALM as WAREHOUSE, 
sa.unidades as UNITS, sa.UBICACION as 'LOCATION' FROM escandallo e 
left join STOCKALM sa on e.codartc = sa.codart AND trim(e.codartp) = '30393' and sa.CODALM = 0
```

Also, have a look on this:

Now, this Query filters all the records which Satisifies from the table (escandallo) "trim(e.codartp) = '30393'" AND the all Columns from the table "STOCKALM" as "NULL" which Shows the Condition mismatch

```
SELECT  e.codartp AS ARTICLE,e.codartc AS COMPONENTS, sa.CODALM as WAREHOUSE, 
sa.unidades as UNITS, sa.UBICACION as 'LOCATION' FROM escandallo e 
left join STOCKALM sa on e.codartc = sa.codart and sa.CODALM = 0
where trim(e.codartp) = '30393'
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed it, thank you. I added the codalm to the join condition and left the codartp as it was. Thank you very much